# hibernate JPA strange prefix on tablename

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

Hi I am using hibernate with spring, liquibase , mariadb and JPA. I just got a strange error and I would guess that this might be a bug in hibernate but I am not totally sure.

I got 2 entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal")
public class Portal 
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AuthorisationCode> authorisationCodes = new HashSet<>();
    ...
 }
```

also

```
@Entity
public class AuthorisationCode
{
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Portal client;
    ...
}
```

and of course a simple Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PortalDao extends JpaRepository<Portal, Long>{}
```

if I now create a portal-object and try to save it **without** adding any authorisation codes I get the following error

```
portalDao.save(portal);
```

=>

```
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Table 'mysqlschema.portal_authorisationcode' doesn't exist
```

why is hibernate adding the prefix "portal_" to the query? I am not even sure why hibernate is even doing a select when the save method is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `mappedBy="client"` to the authorisationCodes set. Looks to me like Hibernate is trying to access a join table portal <-> authorisationcode, because you didn't tell it to do it another way. Just guessing, of course, but it seems like a reasonable default.

Comment: AuthorisationCode does not have `@Column` specified

Comment: @Florian
that solved this problem but also brought a new one...

     org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Unknown column 'authorisat1_.clientid' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you sure there is a column called clientid in the db?

Comment: Did you re-create the database after the update? Since before the error, Hibernate was looking for a table that did not exist, my guess would be you're not re-creating your schema automatically. Do you have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` defined in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I use liquibase for database creation. I am mapping JPA on the generated schema from liquibase. So this should not be a problem

Comment: Then apparently the column is missing, as @Florian Schaetz suggested

Comment: alright got it... the second error is based on wrong mapping from me :-) I mapped it in the wrong direction. Thx :-)